# Blank $_POST var in PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

All I'm trying to do is send a string, in html, to a script written in PHP. I've tried several solutions, including making an html element and putting it in a form and then passing the form (didn't work). I don't know the basics of AJAX or PHP, everything is just kind of being pieced together via what I can google. Here's one way I trying to remedy the situation: (The regexp replaces the first line of the file, which I works. I tried foreach loops with assigning a variable to $_POST[$key], I tried sending just the string with html hoping that would work. I believe the problem lies in the HTML, or in the AJAX call, because I can make the form submit() to the .php file and then it works, however, that would change the browser location to that file and obviously with AJAX, that's not what I want. Anyone have any ideas (other than JQuery syntax)?

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" value="testString">
</form>
```

JavaScript AJAX call

```
function sendString()
{
var data = document.getElementById("test");
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xhr.open('POST', 'testing.php', true);
xhr.send(data);
}
```

PHP File

```
<?php
$line = $_POST['data'];
$file = 'test.txt';
file_put_contents($file,preg_replace('/^.+/',$line,file_get_contents($file),1));
?>
```

EDIT: Thanks for the responses, but non have worked. I tried:

```
document.getElementById("test");
document.getElementById("test").value;
```

and
    xhr.send(data.value);

None of these worked. Still Blank lines. I also tried the extended solution.

Comment: what does $_POST shows in your php file?

Comment: You're sending an element as the data. That's not going to work. You need to send the data in a format that matches your Content-Type.

Comment: You do not extract the value: `xhr.send(data.value);`-

Comment: You want its value, not the DOM element:  `var data = document.getElementById("test").value;`

Comment: Would it not be document.getElementById("test").value ?

Comment: Look at
`file_put_contents($file,print_r($_POST, true));`

Comment: See comment below. It wrote a blank array (Array ()) to the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
var data = document.getElementById("test");
```

You're creating a reference to your html element.  You need to reference the value property of your element.

```
var data = document.getElementById("test").value;
```

Also, you are only sending the value and not a key value pair to the server.  So `xhr.send(data);` will only send the value.  Your PHP script won't know that `$_POST['data']` is what you mean.  You need to format `var data` as

```
var data = "data=" + document.getElementById("test").value;
```

**EDIT**

To send form data via POST, you may need to add some header information.

```
xhr.open('POST', 'testing.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Time to look at what is in $_POST.  I would write the output of `print_r($_POST,true);` to your file.  That will let you see what values are in it.  Don't worry about replacing, just write the value. `file_put_contents($file,print_r($_POST,true));`

Comment: Ahh, so there is probably still a problem with it sending then. I tried this code, the document now only has 

Array
(
)

in it. 

EDIT: Would it matter if I have multiple AJAX calls in the original html document? (separated by functions)

Comment: Try adding this `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` before `xhr.send(data);`

Comment: So after I put your code after I created xhr, but before the send and open request, actually now nothing happens. It doesn't even write to the document anymore.
EDIT- Yep, I used alerts to find out where the processing was stopping. For some reason, it stops running at the setRequestHeader line.

Comment: You need to put it between open and send.  Check out the edit I made on my answer.

Comment: Robbert, you are a genius. Thank you very much. This solves all of my problems, you have no idea how long I was debugging that.

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't forget to mark this as an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Last question, new to Stack Overflow. Do I just click the check mark?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

// change your function

```
function sendString()
{
var data = "data="+document.getElementById("test").value;
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'testing.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(data);
}
```

In testing.php you can call them via $_POST:

`echo $_POST['data'];`

Example here: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/examples/ajax_using_post.php

Comment: I tried adding that, tank you for the commment, but it's still replacing the first line with a blank line. Also, I'm not sure how to approach debugging; I usually use alert() with JS, but the JS console doesn't pull up an error and where would the echo output in the browser window if you're doing it dynamically with AJAX?

Comment: @user3145575 For me this code is working, are you doing the same thing. Please check and you can debug. Put alert in sendString() function like  alert(data) so that you will come to know whether url is correct or not and please let me know what you are getting in alert.

Comment: Right before the send, I used alert(data) (This is with it being set to the HTMLObject.value) and it alerted "data=testing"with no quotes. I know it calls the php script, because the line in that document is getting replaced, but it's always getting replaced with just a bank line.

Comment: Try to add request header, May be it helps you.